# Finding a substring recursively

Tags: c++

Have no idea why this problem is so hard for me.  Iteratively, this is cake but as soon as the stack unwinds it destroys my entire function.

It finds the needle correctly and gives the function a value of true if it finds it.  However, it keeps reverting back to false as soon as the call stack is unwound.  Does anyone know how to remedy this or what I'm doing wrong with my code?

Here is what I have so far...

```
bool mySubStr(char * needle, char * haystack)
{
    int needleLength = strlen(needle);
    int haystackLength = strlen(haystack);
    bool found = false;

    if(needleLength < haystackLength)
    {
        if(strncmp(haystack, needle, needleLength) == 0)
        {
            found = true;
        }
        else
        {
            mySubStr(needle, haystack + 1);
        }
    }

    return found;
}
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you could be specific about the result you expected, the result you actually got and the steps you have taken so far to understand or resolve the problem.

Comment: The result I expected was true when I the needle = "sip" and the haystack = "Mississippi".  The result I actually got was false.  The steps I've taken to resolve the problem were numerous.  I don't even know where to begin.

Comment: Just add a little code in your else block: found = mySubStr(needle, haystack + 1);

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to return the result of the recursive call to `mySubStr(..)`:

```
bool mySubStr(char * needle, char * haystack)
{
   int needleLength = strlen(needle);
   int haystackLength = strlen(haystack);

   if(needleLength > haystackLength)
       return false;

   if(strncmp(haystack, needle, needleLength) == 0)
   {
       return true;
   }

   return mySubStr(needle, haystack + 1);          
}
```

In your implementation, you were calling the function recursively but were discarding the result:

```
  else
  {
     mySubStr(needle, haystack + 1);
  }
}

return found;
```

So in effect, unless the *needle* happened to be right at the beginning, your function would always return false.

Comment: Or he can do this: found = mySubStr(needle, haystack + 1);

Comment: @Miky Dinescu -- Wow, thank you so much!!  xuwicha, I tried that and it kept giving me the same problem.  Reverted found to false when the stack calls unwound.

Comment: @MrPickle5: Also add "=" in your 1st if condition: if(needleLength <= haystackLength){}